# Token returned as [object Object] ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I am using import { Stripe } from '@ionic-native/stripe' to create card token but the function createCardToken() is returning object Object

this.stripe.createCardToken(card).then(token => alert('transaction Successfull!!'+token))
.catch(error => alert('error'+error));

[image]

How do i get the sting of the token?

The following is the prototype of the createCardToken
 createCardToken(params: StripeCardTokenParams): Promise;

Comment: You got `[object Object]` because you forced an object into a string context, by concatenating it to a string value in your alert. Start by using console.log instead of alert for debugging purposes, and then inspect the object you got here in the browser console, to find out what properties it has.

Comment: cannot use console log since i cant run the app in browser as it needs cordova

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass into `JSON.stringify(token)`

Comment: so far so good im able to view the JSON but whenever i try to access id it gives an error

Comment: got it JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(token) to access id

Answer (score 0):

according to docs @ https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/stripe/

the returned token is indeed an object.You probably want to access it's id property:

`this.stripe.createCardToken(card)
   .then(token => console.log(token.id))
   .catch(error => console.error(error));`

Comment: Yes tried that already, but im gettign an error saying 'Property id does not exists on type string